# LuisActionDialog is obsolete - how to work with LuisActionBinding?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am reading and learning the code from: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/Blog-LUISActionBinding

And then I wanted to plug this in my own project but `LuisActionBinding` is not working with `LuisDialog`. And [I read that `LuisActionDialog` API is now obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.luisactiondialog?view=botbuilder-3.12.2.4)

Can you point me to the right direction on how to go forward?

Comment: What are you trying to implement? A bot using LUIS?

Comment: @NicolasR yes, I have LUIS Bot and I am now learning adaptive cards. Alongside that I came across `LuisActionDialog` + `LuisActionBinding` and I want to know how to integrate that with my bot.

Comment: I'm not sure that you need `LuisActionBinding` in that case

Comment: @NicolasR That's right, I don't _need_ it. I am hoping to learn it anyways for when the need does arise. Is it a code structure kind of issue where if I don't build my bot with that in mind, then I can't really integrate it afterwards?

Comment: Honestly, never used that besides the fact that I made several projects (bots or not) using LUIS intensively

Comment: @Oyen did the answer solve your issue? You might consider marking that as your favourite answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I read that LuisActionDialog API is now obsolete

The `LuisActionDialog` API which is obsoleted is in the `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs` namespace, and in the official [LUIS Action Binding Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/Blog-LUISActionBinding), the `LuisActionDialog` is under the namespace `Microsoft.Cognitive.LUIS.ActionBinding.Bot`.

This `Microsoft.Cognitive.LUIS.ActionBinding.Bot` package is not released, if you want to use that `LuisActionDialog`, you need to download the sample, and there's source code of this package.

This is a reported issue and you can refer to [it here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/206).